# DynamoDB access by last modified

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Hey I have a pretty simple requirement for Dynamo in that a get endpoint (by id) all good table has a partition key set to an integer id.

And then a get all not ideal but hey that’s the requirement.

I also have an additional requirement to getAll where lastModified > yesterday (to mitigate requirement 2 from costing a small fortune)

What I don’t get is how I should set this up. A sort key on the main id seems like it would result in scanning every partition.

Should I also setup a gsi with a partition key something like lastModifiedDay and a sortkey being the unix timestamp to help divvy up the work.

Any help would be amazing

Tried exploring the docs but that didn’t yield much as there seems to always be a natural group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve it is to create a GSI with a static value as the partition key, and timestamp as your sort key.

| GSIPK | GSISK | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-25T20:00:000 | 123 |
| 1 | 2023-11-25T21:00:000 | 016 |
| 1 | 2023-11-25T22:00:000 | 912 |
| 1 | 2023-11-26T20:00:000 | 400 |

Now a query on your index will give you exactly what you require, efficiently.

`SELECT * FROM mytable.myindex WHERE GSIPK = 1 AND GSISK > (YESTERDAY)`

*Note: this suggests you don't have more than 1000 WCU consumption on your base table. If you do, you will need to shard the static value of `1`*

Comment: Thanks for the reply would it make sense for the gsipk to be something like yyyy-mm-dd to further shard out all those redundant values? I could make the api only let you go back x days and have select all where gsipk in (yyyy-mm-dd,etc)

Comment: It depends. If you need more than 1000 WCU throughput, then it may make more sense. Having a static value as 1 can allow you to efficiently query up to millisecond precision. Using date as the partition key will not provide you that flexibility.

Comment: The way this answer starts off seems misleading to me “ The best way to achieve it is to create a GSI with a static value as the partition key” — this makes it seem like this is acceptable practice and even something people are encouraged to do. Maybe it’s ok to say you can do this in certain cases but really, you probably shouldn’t is more like how I would start this answer

Comment: Thanks Mike. Why shouldn't you do this, and what alternative do you suggest?